Weakly compact set
I want to show that if the set
$$
\big\{u \in L^{q}([0, n] ; X): u(t) \in \phi(t, x(t)), t \in[0, n]\big\}
$$
is weakly compact, then  the set
$$
\mathcal{S}_{\phi}(x)=\Big\{u\in L_{loc}^{q}(\mathbb{R}^{+},X):u(t)\in \phi(t, x(t))\text{ for a.e. }t\in \mathbb{R}^{+}  \Big\}
$$ is weakly compact too.
I made my own attempt in this way: let's consider a sequence $(u_k)_{k\geq 1}\subset \mathcal{S}_{\phi}(x)$. We must show that there exists a subsequence $(u_{k_n})_{{k_n}\geq 1}$ that converges weakly. To do so, we proceed by a standard diagonal selection process. For each $n \in \mathbb{N}$, we consider the restriction of the sequence $(u_k)$ to the interval $[0, n]$.

For $n = 1$, there exists a subsequence $(u_k^{(1)})$ that converges weakly in $L^q([0, 1], X)$. Let's denote this subsequence by $(u_{k_1})$.
For $n = 2$, we consider the subsequence $(u_{k_1})$ restricted to $[0, 2]$. There exists a sub-subsequence of $(u_{k_1})$, denoted by $(u_{k_2})$, that converges weakly in $L^q([0, 2], X)$.
We continue this process. For $n = 3$, we consider the sub-subsequence $(u_{k_2})$ restricted to $[0, 3]$ and find a sub-sub-subsequence $(u_{k_3})$ that converges weakly in $L^q([0, 3], X)$.
We repeat this process for each $n \in \mathbb{N}$, selecting at each step a subsequence of the previous subsequence.

The diagonal selection process gives us a nested sequence of sequences $(u_{k_n})$ such that each $(u_{k_{n+1}})$ is a subsequence of $(u_{k_n})$ and $(u_{k_n})$ converges weakly in $L^q([0, n], X)$.
Simply denoting $(v_n) = (u_{k_n})$, we have $v_n \rightarrow v_0$ weakly in $L^q([0, n], X)$ for each $n$.
I want to show that the sequence $(v_n)$ converges weakly to $v_0$ in $L_{loc}^q(\mathbb{R}^+, X)$, I do not how to achieve it. Any suggestions please?
